# Internet Explorer 11 bloquea codigo

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, asp

hoy vengo con esta cuestión, en un proyecto en el cual se trabaja con ASP.net, ASP clasico utilizo el siguiente código para abrir una ventana secundaria de ASP.net

```
dim strSearch  : strSearch  = request.querystring("search")
pick = " onclick='window.open(&#39;/dana/Proyectall/Engineering/form_PickList/Default.aspx?WorkOrder=" &work&"&Assembly="&strSearch& "&#39;,&#39;&#39;, &#39;scrollbars=yes,width=1500px,height=900px,return false,resizable=YES&#39;);'"
```

El problema es que por ejemplo cuando accedo a la interfaz por IP "192.168.1.120" todo se muestra bien pero cuando accedo por dominio me bloque muchas cosas o no las toma en cuenta (No muestra scrollbars, no pueden modificar el tamaño de la ventana,la barra de navegación desaparece), nada de esto pasa cuando accedo por IP.
Alguna idea de por que pase lo anterior?

Comment: comprobaste si te está cargando bien los archivos css y js?

Comment: Los css y js cargan bien, es el mismo servidor, solo que la diferencia es de la manera de acceder, por la ip se muestra bien pero cuando quieres acceder por el dominio no carga ni js ni css

Comment: y en consola te arroja algún error? también puede que IE esté configurado con seguridad estricta. bloqueo de js, etc. Todo eso es configurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví, no tenia nada que ver con permisos ni seguridad, en mi proyecto agregue las siguientes 2 lineas de código:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=9; IE=11" />
```

Se agregan enseguida del head y son para que el proyecto sea compatible con IE 
Espero que a alguien en el futuro le sirva.